# Filter in Apache Spark is not working expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'am executing the code below:

```
ordersRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/orders")
orderItemsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/order_items")

ordersParsedRDD = ordersRDD.filter(lambda rec: rec.split(",")[3] in "CANCELED").map(lambda rec: (int(rec.split(",")[0]), rec))
orderItemsParsedRDD = orderItemsRDD.map(lambda rec: (int(rec.split(",")[1]), float(rec.split(",")[4])))
orderItemsAgg = orderItemsParsedRDD.reduceByKey(lambda acc, value: (acc + value))

ordersJoinOrderItems = orderItemsAgg.join(ordersParsedRDD)

for i in ordersJoinOrderItems.filter(lambda rec: rec[1][0] >= 1000).take(5): print(i)
```

final results are not getting displayed for me, display stops at this condition.

before `Join` command I was able to display all records, after `Join` data is not getting displayed.
The error is shown below:

```
16/06/01 17:26:05 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 12 non-empty blocks out of 12 blocks
16/06/01 17:26:05 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/06/01 17:26:05 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 67, boot = -57, init = 61, finish = 63
16/06/01 17:26:05 INFO python.PythonRunner: Times: total = 73, boot = -68, init = 75, finish = 66
16/06/01 17:26:05 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 11.0 in stage 289.0 (TID 2689). 1461 bytes result sent to driver
16/06/01 17:26:05 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 11.0 in stage 289.0 (TID 2689) in 153 ms on localhost (12/24)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by printing the count on ordersJoinOrderItems. If it is bigger than 0, it would then suggest your filter is the culprit.